# Use layout as background of another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Couldn't find this even though seems simple.

My question is simple, I have the following login layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignupActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="All fields are required."
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/usernametext"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

And I made another layout with just takes an ImageView and put it to the center with certain alpha.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/mtrigenicon"
        android:alpha="0.25"
        android:scaleX="3"
        android:scaleY="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Question is, It is possible to use the second layout as background of the first?, I mean, to use the ImageView below all the EditText and TextViews of the first layout, even integrating the ImageView on the first layout can work as a solution, but I don't know how to make it to be on the background and below all the other objects.

Comment: You can try looking into `FrameLayout`. That might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can include the imageview directly as background of login layout. Otherwise if you want to use second layout as background for any layout you can use `<include` tag in android xml.

Simply set your root layout to `FrameLayout` in which layout you want include background layout.

**Like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_background" /> //Here is the include part. Below as same as previous.

<LinearLayout                  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="All fields are required."
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/usernametext"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"/>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_background.xml** (Same as your layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/canoe_water_nature_480_670"
    android:alpha="0.25"
    android:scaleX="3"
    android:scaleY="3" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Try using this layout.

In xml views are drawn in the order you put them, so just put the image view first, and draw the linear layout on top. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/mtrigenicon"
    android:alpha="0.25"
    android:scaleX="3"
    android:scaleY="3" />


     Put your linear layout here
    <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LinearLayout use RelativeLayout in your first layout and add your ImageView to it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SignupActivity"    
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/mtrigenicon"
    android:alpha="0.25"
    android:scaleX="3"
    android:scaleY="3" />
<TextView
    android:id="+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    android:layout_below="id/your_imageview_id"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="All fields are required."
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="id/text1"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"/>

<-- your rest of the layout -->

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Make sure to configure your layout according to your requirement because LinearLayout does that automatically, but in RelativeLayout you have to do it on your own.